# Asymptotic behavior of solution to an initial boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I solved an initial boundary value problem, but I have been stuck trying to prove a certain limit. I will post the problem and my progress so far for completeness.

**Problem**

Solve the initial boundary value problem for $t>0$:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
4u_{tt}(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)-7u(x,t),&0<x<\pi\\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi,t)=0\\
u(x,0)=4\cos^3x,&0<x<\pi\\
u_t(x,0)=\cos(5x),&0<x<\pi.
\end{array}
$$

Find $\lim_{t\to\infty} u(x,t)$ as a function of $x$.

**Solution to first part**

For the solution to the problem, I used separation of variables and expanded $4\cos^3 x$ as $3\cos x+\cos(3x)$. The solution I found was:

$$
u(x,t)=3\cos(\sqrt{2}t)\cos x+\cos(2t)\cos(3x)+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\sin(2\sqrt{2}t)\cos(5x).
$$

This satisfies each condition imposed above in the statement of the problem.

**Question**

How would one find $\lim_{t\to\infty} u(x,t)$? It seems to me that I cannot directly apply the limit to the solution $u(x,t)$ as I wrote above since $u(x,t)$ is a sum of periodic functions in $t$. I'm almost thinking there is no limit unless I'm missing something. Also, is there some physical insight into what is happening in this particular problem?